# xero API works on local server but not on production server

Tags: cakephp-3.0, xero-api

I have the strange issue of my crm (cakephp3)was integrated with Xero Api and works fine. I zipped the folder and uploaded it to the live server for testing and on this server (linux php5.6) I am getting this error below and none of the Xero works.
The boostrap file and the certs are all there as they have been uploaded from the development server . Obviously is something to do with the certs of the consumer_key but everything is there?

XeroOAuth::request() Missing required consumer_key in OAuthSimple.signatures

Does anyone have any idea and as I said the xero development all works on my local server? Not sure what else I can say to add clarity to my problem .  The oauth module is enabled and I tried it without and that didnt fix anything. The security key works fine on my local server.

Comment: Found the answer as the paths on linux are different to windows and this fixed the weird error message.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer as the paths on linux are different to windows and this fixed the weird error message when I changed the paths on a xero api file